# how to make a session last for 5 hours?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I am developing an application which has a powerpoint presentation. Users are required to go through it and then accept an agreement. The users login in details are stored in the session object.when they finish the read the session object will expired. I used the following code in web.config with no effect what so ever.

```
 <system.web>
<sessionState timeout="500" />
```

is there any setting i need to change in the IIS ? i am using iis 8.5

Comment: nice question, but needs a lot of write... do you have read anything about session ?

Comment: i am not really an administrator. just had to fill in temporarily. i went through some article where i found the above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change the idleTimeout int your IIS. You can see this configuration on the advanced settings of the application pool of your IIS

Follow this article to change the session time out

[Change IIS time out](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8a96bbb8-4c28-44e8-ac91-5252cb117550)

For IIS 6
There is a Session Timeout setting in Properties -> Home Directory Tab -> Configuration button -> Options tab. Looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Idle Time-out (minutes) box is missing from my iis

Comment: i am using iis 8.5